# hypothesis testing highway lanes problem

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have the following problem which I'm trying to solve:

We have a highway with four lanes. A research with 1000 drivers is made to check whether the drivers prefer the inner lanes. There are the following results:

Lane 1: 294,
Lane 2: 276,
Lane 3: 238,
Lane 4: 192.

Do the data give enough information to prove that the proportions all the lanes are different?

Test $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4=0.25$ when $\alpha=0.05$.

**My attempt:**

My interpretation is that $H_0$ claims that the distribution is Normal distribution with $\mu=2.5$ and that I have to construct a two-tailed test with $Z_{0.025}=\pm1.96$.

My test-statistic is:

$t=\frac{(\bar X-\mu)\sqrt{n}}{s}=\frac{10(2.32800-2.5)}{s}=\frac{-1.72}{s}$, where s is the sample standard deviation.

Is my attempt alright, and if so, how do I find the sample standard deviation so that I test my hypothesis?

Comment: It is clearly not normally distributed as it can only take four values.  But for what it is worth, the sample standard deviation is $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_i n_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2}{\left( \sum_i n_i \right)-1}}$ where $\bar{x} = \dfrac{\sum_i n_i x_i}{ \sum_i n_i }$ and here is about $s \approx 1.0925$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Chi-Squared Test with the statistic

$\chi^2 = \sum_{1}^{4} \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i} = A$

with $O_i$ is observed proportion and $E_i = .25$

Test with compute $\chi^2_{critical}$ P(X^2>=A) in a chi-square distribution with df being 3 and compare it with p = 0.05 and reject the nukl hypothesis that $H_0: p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4$ if $\chi^2_{critical}$ is greater than 0.05.

Thanks

Comment: OK, so I get that $A=0.027160$ and $X^2_{critical}$ = pchisq(0.027160, 3) = 0.001180803. In that case $X^2_{critical}$ is less than 0.05 and we cannot reject the null hypothesis. Correct?

Comment: I have not worked out the problem.  Seems like if you have done the calculations correctly, you conclusion is right

Answer (score 1):

You need to  use test for multiple proportions e.g the Marascuillo-test.

See:
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc474.htm

Comment: What is $n_i$ in my case?

Comment: n_{1} = 294, n_{2}=276, n_{3}= 238, n_{4}=192. See exemplary R-code.